# How to call dynamic styles in angular2

Tags: angular

I hereby tried to call the **themeColor** variable in .activeLink class, but it's not working. Is it any way to get the value dynamically? please help.

```
 styles:[`
    .activeLink{
        background:${this.themeColor} !important;
        color: #fff !important;
    }
`]


export class NavBarComponent implements OnInit{
  themeColor = "#ff0"
}
```

HTML

```
<a [routerLink]="['/public']" routerLinkActive="activeLink" 
[routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:true}"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> {{ 
'home.menu.home' | translate }}</a>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no interpolation support for styles in Angular

You can use

```
<some-element [style.background-color]="themeColor"
```

Comment: I want to change the background color dynamically using class

Comment: Then use `[class.my-class]="isMyClass"` or `[ngClass]="{'my-class': isMyClass}"`

Comment: bro, is it possible to add the styles without using class name in "routerLinkActive"?

Comment: Seems you're making quite big jumps without much details. Sorry, but I can't follow what you try to accomplish.

Comment: previous I have used routerLinkActive="active", and "active" is my class and which is return in my stylesheet. but now I want to change the "active" class background color dynamically and the "color" value receiving from localstorage.

Comment: `[routerLinkActive]="activeClassField"`, then assign the class you want to the  `activeClassFiled` field in your components class.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148189/discussion-between-sridhar-and-gunter-zochbauer).